# cmake files not found while building Azure IoT edge in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: azure, iot, windowsiot

I am trying to **install azure IoT edge** on a **raspberry pi 3.0** to forward device-to-cloud messages to **IoT hub**. I took the help of the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-iot-edge-physical-device

When I'm trying to build the Azure IoT edge using the command "./tools/build.sh" ,
the following error comes up.
"**Cmake error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:646(message): None of the required 'gio-unix-2.0' found.**

**Configuring incomplete, errors occured!**
Please help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is you system **Raspbian Linux**? Do you ran this step "**Install the BlueZ dependencies:**" ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Raspbian linux. I did not install BlueZ dependencies as it was already installed when I was working with Watson IoT.

Comment: Are you sure that glib2.0 installed on your device?

Comment: Okay. I started afresh. I installed the  blueZ dependencies. But again, I got stuck in that same step : **./tools/build.sh**

Comment: The following error comes up. **fatal error: uv. H: No such file or directory**         **#include<UV.h> ^ connection terminated**

Answer (score 0):

Today i had this same issue and solved it by doing the following;

1. ./tools/build_libuv.sh This returned an error autogen.sh 43: autogen.sh: libtoolize: not found (https://github.com/beakerbrowser/beaker/issues/54)
2. sudo apt-get install libtool
3. after libtool finished installing I then executed ./tools/build_libuv.sh
   This completed successfully
4. ./tools/build.sh

I now have iot-edge running on my Raspberry pi 3